# Equivalent of "host" network with docker-compose for containers running on windows

Tags: windows, docker, networking, port

I'm using docker-compose on linux. In my compose-file I have `network_mode: "host"` for bunch of containers. This is convenient for my stack to able to access my containers as `localhost:<port>`.

Now I've had to run this on windows and it doesn't work. I've read this in the docs:

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not
> supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or
> Docker EE for Windows Server.

So.... anyways I have to access my container's exposed port on windows by some other means, as localhost:port as I on linux? Or do I HAVE to map them out to some random IP and access something like 3.70.0.1:port on windows?

Comment: All systems with Docker Desktop should be able to normally use Docker's core port mapping feature (Compose `ports:`) to make services available on `localhost`.  This works even when disabling Docker networking with `network_mode: host` doesn't.  Can you use `ports:` instead?

Comment: (With `ports:` you do not get "some random IP", you access the container using the host system's IP address or DNS name, or `localhost` if you're on the same system.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I synthetized that in an actual answer. About the "random ip", well no not random, however if you do multiple runs and/or have other containers running, they may bump last bit of the IP address up (e.g. from 172.0.10.1 to 172.0.10.2), so they aren't fixed on each run. Hence my somewhat innacurate comment about "random". I meant variable.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify this question and related issue. See comments on the question for details.

Indeed, simply specifying

```
ports: <host>:<container>
```

allows you to access your container/services as `localhost:<host>` from the host on linux/windows (likely mac too). That being said, specifying `network_mode: host` in your docker-compose.yaml service definition actually *disables* this on windows (and likely mac) systems.

A related issue I was having was that in some of my service, the IP address for communication between containers was of the type `localhost:<container>`. If you use network_mode: host, then indeed from both the host and container's perspective, the service run on localhost. However if you just use port mapping, then while the service run on localhost from the host's perspective, they then run on docker's private network from the service's perspective. So they will expect an IP address of the form `<service_name>:<container_port>` to communicate between containers.